# Как построить график разрывной функции?

Tags: python, математика, matplotlib, графики

Я построил график функции путем создания двух прямых, не включающих в себя точку разрыва:

```
xList1 = np.arange(a, -5-h, h)
xList2 = np.arange(-5+h, b, h)

lineF1 = plt.plot(xList1, f(xList1), color='b', linewidth=2.0)
lineF2 = plt.plot(xList2, f(xList2), color='b', linewidth=2.0)
```

Для удобства, хотелось бы объединить xList1 и xList2, но в таком случае на графике не образуется разрыв, а точки, которые должны были быть на границах разрыва, соединяются. Есть ли способ избежать этого и построить график правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для того чтобы получить разрыв достаточно заменить значения по `X` и `Y` - `NaN` (Not a Number):

```
In [150]: x = np.linspace(-7, 7, 100)

In [151]: x[(x>-1) & (x<2)] = np.nan

In [152]: plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
Out[152]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x2aac7c72278>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В моей случаем координаты по x дробные числа ( например 1.1 , -5.000000018) и при попытке таким способом отфильтровать этот список у меня возникает ошибка IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor, можете привести в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных? Кстати в моем примере данные - тоже дробные числа - попробуйте запустить первую строку и напечатать `x`...

Comment: xList = np.linspace(-10,10,20/0.1)
    xList[(x>=-5.1) & (x<-5.0)] = np.nan

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor, `xList[(xList>=-5.1) & (xList<-5.0)] = np.nan` - замечательно работает ;)

Comment: А,понял, какая же глупая ошибка, спасибо большое)